# ASP WebForms DropDownList weird behavior on IE7

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer-7, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm building a page in ASP Webforms in the login page I have a drop down list that it's working fine on Chrome, Firefox and IE Edge but when I change to compatibility mode in IE7 there is an estrange behavior after clicking the list the form moves and click other side back to its original position.

[image]

This is after click

[image]

This is the html for the dropdown list

```
<div>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlLocation" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 5px; color: rgb(175, 175, 175); font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
    <asp:ListItem>Location</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

and this are their CSS

```
.loginContainer .login select {
    *margin-left: -10px !important;
}
.loginContainer .login select {
    width: 180px;
    color:#898883;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.loginContainer .login input[type=text], .loginContainer .login input[type=password], .loginContainer .login select {
   height: 40px;
   border: 1px solid #979797;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight:lighter;
   color: #36333D;
   width:99.8%;
   margin-top:15px;
   line-height:40px
}
```

Comment: Try doing a View Source both before and after clicking the list. My guess is that the list has AutoPostback set to *true*, and what is sent back from the server after the POST is missing a containing DIV or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer but I checked bot states and there is no difference, I found that the parent div was using overflow:auto and just in the IE7 gives error I removed the property and now it's working